# SQL Server Collation And Case Insensitive Identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

We have an old SQL Server database with case sensitive collation, but our newer application code expects *column and table names* to be case insensitive.

So, we are trying to convert the database so that the column and table names will be case insensitive.

The solution so far is to create an empty DB with case insensitive collation, then generating scripts from the old database to recreate the schema in the new database (using SQL Server Studio), then exporting the data from the old database into the new database.

This *almost* works, but the old instance allowed for a couple of rows of data that are identical when ignoring case sensitivity and we have a unique constraint violation.

Is there a simple way to allow for SQL references to table and column names to be insensitive while column data is treated as sensitive still (without having to modify the columns individually with separate collations)?

Comment: Just to make sure -- have you considered convincing the application guys to make their code case-clean? It might be painful, but it really *ought* to work with a database that chooses to use a case-sensitive collation, exactly to avoid gruntwork like this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That will be the long term solution, but we need to resolve this quickly in the short term.

Comment: I changed my answer where I said "no", because on further reflection I think the actual answer is "yes". :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, I think that's what we want. I need to check the application code to make sure this will be ok, but I think I want to have CI identifiers and CS column data (like Oracle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a database, the system tables that hold the object names get the collation of the database -- here you want an insensitive collation. If you then want all your data to be case sensitive still, change the database's default collation, then run your scripts.

Changing the collation will not change the collation of already created objects (including the system tables) but it will affect subsequent objects.

Without changing the column collation at all, you can override it on individual queries, for example `WHERE A = 'Hi' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI`, but this is inefficient because it will prevent the use of indexes for seeking (as conversions are required). It's not possible to define a constraint with a collation override -- you'd have to get complicated and define it on a computed column with a separate collation.

Comment: I'm curious about the comment related to constraints. If we have a CI collation for the db, and CS collation for column data, how will a unique constraint for that column function? Will it be CS?

Comment: Yes, it will be CS. Constraints follow the column data. But as you say that, now I'm not sure if the database default collation is used for other things than object creation -- in particular, what will happen to parameters and if you will get collation errors if you just do naive comparisons.

Comment: Tested it -- stored procedures and queries will "do the right thing" for parameters regardless of the database collation. That is, if your data is CS, your query will likewise perform a CS comparison, regardless of the current database collation. It's only when you're directly comparing columns with different collations that you have a problem.